# spring form-login in the site front page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

How should i configure sptring security (using xml) to allow the front page of my app to be also the login form (it has the form control on the upper right of the page)?.

So far i've been using the security.xml:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
<!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->

<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

<!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
<!--  -->
<security:form-login login-processing-url="/loginProcess" login-page="/front" default-target-url="/front" />
<security:logout logout-url="/logout"/>
```

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

being fron.jsp by front web page and /loginprocess the controller for the login:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginProcess(ModelMap model) {

            //<do login here>
    return "front";
}
```

Comment: You don't need a controller spring security handles the login. It doesn't matter where it comes from as long as the post goes to the url defined by the `login-processing-url` property.

Comment: So i have the security configured as: {<security:form-login login-processing-url="/loginProcess" login-page="/front" default-target-url="/front"/>.} The <form> contained in front.jsp will need to be poitning to "/loginProcess". will that handle all the logging? what is the resource handling the POST from the form?. Thank you!

Comment: Spring Security handles the login, would be kind of a useless security framework if you would have to write login/logout yourself wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: First configure your "front.jsp" in web.xml file as **welcome file**

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>front.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Step 2: Second configure your "front.jsp" file in security.xml as **login-page**

```
<security:form-login login-page="/front.jsp"
            default-target-url="/welcome.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.jsp" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.jsp" />
```

Step 3: Third configure your request url in your controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/front", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {

        return "front";

    }
```

like

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "front";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {

        return "front";

    }
```

Note : front.jsp, welcome.jsp,logout.jsp was change as per your viewResolver is written

```
Example: <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Listen!! here you need to use .html extension instead .jsp

Thanks

Comment: Thanks you @Kanhu Bhol. The thing is i want the landing page the same as the post login one. That is, the users not logged will see the login form, but once login is successful, the form will be replaced with user-info like "inbox messages"...etc In your security.xml should i replace the "welcome.jsp" with "front.jsp" so the page is the same and modify the /front to detect the user object?